# How does xdg-open do its work

Tags: desktop-environment, freedesktop, xdg-open

According to the man page, `xdg-open` will open a file using the application the user has configured. But how is that application actually determined? I can see no config files associated with `xdg-utils`, so where are my settings stored and how can I modify them? Seeing how a simple PNG file opens Internet Explorer using Wine, I need to change these settings.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look at the content of the `xdg-open` file, and you will notice that it is a simple shell script. Its main task is identifying the desktop environment in use, which will then be used to delegate the task to a specific tool:

- **KDE** delegates to `kde-open` or `kfmclient`
- **Gnome** delegates to `gvfs-open` or `gnome-open`
- **Mate** delegates to `gvfs-open` or `mate-open`
- **XFCE** delegates to `exo-open`
- **LXDE** delegates to `pcmanfm`, with fallback to “generic” for most URLs
- **Enlightenment** delegates to `enlightenment_open`
- Everything else is termed “**generic**”, and the script tries its own luck

So the core message is this: in most situations, one of these delegates will do the actual work, so you should check about how these are configured.

For example, I'm running XFCE, so `xdg-open` calls `exo-open` which uses the XFCE settings available through the XFCE settings user interface and stored in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

For details about the config files in use, `strace -e file` can be useful. And if you are in the “generic” situation and want to see what `xdg-open` itself does, you can try `` sh -x `which xdg-open` file.name ``.

Comment: [Similar answer](http://superuser.com/a/918994/139893) for different question. :-)