# Why do desktop environments make custom xdg-open replacements?

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop, xdg-open, xdg

Related to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59088/13428) on my previous question.

So, XDG can handle it on its own:

- It can manage default applications - `xdg-mime`
- It can open file with associated application - `xdg-open`.

Why do desktop environments make their own replacements for `xdg-open`? Like `gvfs-open`, `kde-open`, or `exo-open`,...

Isn't `xdg-open` enough? If not, what does it lack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Arch Wiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open):

> Inside a desktop environment (e.g. GNOME, KDE, or Xfce), `xdg-open` simply passes the arguments to that desktop environment's file-opener application (`gvfs-open`, `kde-open`, or `exo-open`, respectively), which means that the associations are left up to the desktop environment. When no desktop environment is detected (for example when one runs a standalone window manager, e.g. Openbox), `xdg-open` will use its own configuration files.

So, they are not replacements, but backends.

Comment: This presumably allows the DE's freedom to, e.g., implement functionality that may not be provided by `xdg-open`.

Comment: @goldilocks Rather, it's to allow e.g. PDF files to be opened by Okular under KDE, Evince under Gnome, etc.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144047/how-does-xdg-open-do-its-work has more about how the delegation works.

Comment: @Gilles That's not "rather", that's "as in" ;)